# Differences between "sledge", "sleigh" and "sled"

Tags: differences, synonyms, dialects, variants

Is there a difference between a sledge, a sleigh and a sled?

[Dictionary definitions suggest they are synonymous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sledge), but it certainly sounds wrong to refer to Santa Claus on a ***sledge***.

Comment: A thread on the question on *linguaphiles*: [Sled/sledge/sleigh](http://linguaphiles.livejournal.com/4174520.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A *sledge* is normally taken to mean ‘a carriage mounted upon runners instead of wheels, and generally used for travelling over snow or ice’. It shares its etymology and meaning with *sled*, a form which the OED describes as being ‘chiefly dialect and US’.  It does, however, have some meanings that *sledge* does not have. They include ‘any of various devices made to be towed along the sea bed’ and ‘a kind of river-boat used on the Ohio’.
*Sleigh* has the same etymology, but generally describes a sledge which can be drawn by horses.

Comment: Do you think it is necessary and important to remember this distinction when using the words? Is there a more frequently used word among them with a broader meaning?

Comment: @Kris: I think it is helpful to distinguish between what a child slides down a snow-covered slope on, and what rich people ride through Gstaad on.

Comment: If *bob-sled* is a sub-type of a word only used in non-standard dialects, there are a lot of yokels in winter sports. (Great answer, BTW.)

Comment: @Barrie: _“… drawn by horses”_ – or reindeer, of course :-)

Comment: I’d add that there also exists a somewhat specialised use of _sled_: it’s a device used to mount a hard disk drive inside a computer.  You can’t substitute _sleigh_ or _sledge_ in this case.

Comment: Even "sleigh" is regional - in the Northeastern U.S., I encountered usage of "sleigh" to mean "sled", i.e., not horse-drawn.

Comment: Sled also has a specific engineering meaning of a carriage that slides on a smooth surface. So bridge sections might be moved into position by on a sled by hydraulic rams

Answer (score 10):

There is a difference among American, British, and others; I'll give (my) AmE interpretation.

- sleigh - a vehicle like an open-air carriage, pulled by horses, using runners instead of wheels for use in winter on snow/ice.
- sled - a small single person conveyance to slide down hills, usually has runners, but may just have a flat bottom.
- sledge - any kind of flat conveyance to be dragged over the ground. These are used for conveyance large loads or injured people when a wheeled vehicle is not available. The references I have seen define 'sledge' almost identically to 'sleigh'. I would never use 'sledge' for Santa's kind of sleigh, nor would I use it for a child's winter toy. 'Sledge' is pretty rare in AmE.

Answer (score 7):

In the US, here would be images of how I define each sledge, sleigh, and sled, despite all of them having a similar definition in the dictionary.

Sledge:[image: sledgehammer]

Sleigh:[image: santa's sleigh]

Sled:[image: kid on sled]

However, snowmobilers often call their snowmobile a sled, as well:[image: Arctic Cat]

Note: All images came from a Google image search and are presumably copyright of their respective picture takers.

Comment: Your "sled" image (with the child) is a **sledge** in UK English.  And your "sledge" (first pic) would be a **sledge hammer**.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to say that a *sleigh* or *sled* are pulled by animals - for example Reindeer in Santa's sleigh or a dog sled.  A sledge is self-propelled, hence why children, at least in the UK, are referred to as sledging rather than sleighing or sledding (though I have heard sledding occasionally; I would not say that it is in common use however).

Comment: Not when it is a bob-s... with the official organisations called *Fédération Internationale de Bobsleigh et de Tobogganing*, *United States Bobsled and Skeleton Federation* and *Bobsleigh Canada Skeleton*.

Comment: I can well imagine a Briton going "sledging" on a "sled", just to confuse matters.

Comment: Interesting, as in American usage the words sled and sleigh have seemingly opposite connotation, see Barrie England's comment to his own answer.  Indeed, many children in Canada and the northern parts of the U.S. look forward to riding down hills in round or oblong plastic devices this time of year, and most call this device a sled.

Comment: @Wade Actually in canada we call the round ones saucers and the ones without runners and rounded at the front (made of wood, aluminum, or plastic) are toboggans. If it has runners or skis it's a sled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that (like the various words for bread rolls, or the pronunciation of "scone"), the meanings of these three variations on the word vary widely by location, social class and social circle.

Most UK children will only get the opportunity to use a sled/sledge/sleigh every couple of years, when there's an unusually generous snowfall, so the words are not in frequent enough use for a true standard to emerge.

In parts of the English speaking world where snow is more guaranteed, I strongly suspect you'd find clusters of each word.